# ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class which was declared in manifest

Tags: java, android, activitynotfoundexception

I'm trying to send content through Intent (I think this is the reason of my error) and I constantly get `ActivityNotFoundException`. 
Here's the class which is sending data to `Tab1.class` (String called temperature)

I found similar question on stack where someone wrote that problem is caused by instantiating the intent before the activity has gone through its life cycle methods but I'm not sure if it is a problem and what should I do to fix it

```
public class ChooseLayout extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editText;
    Button button;
    Weather weather;
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    String temperature, preassure,WindSpeed,WindDirection,Humidity,ViewDescription;
    boolean isChecked = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choose_layout);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!isOnline()) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot connect to network, data will be restore from file with last downloaded data...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                weather = parser.getWeatherForLocation(editText.getText() + "");
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        editText.setText(weather.getCity() + ",  " + weather.getCountry());
                                         temperature = weather.getTemperature();
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    t.start();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tab1.class);
                intent.putExtra("temperature", temperature);
                startActivity(intent);


            }
        });
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
```

I have declared this activity in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chirag.slidingtabsusingviewpager">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ChooseLayout"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Does `Tab1` extend `Activity`? Could you post a snipped showing the class definition for `Tab1`?

Comment: @lase - public class Tab1 extends Fragment

Answer (score 0):

You can either add or replace fragment in your activity.

Then do this in your activity to `add` fragment:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(android.R.id.content, tab1);
transaction.commit();
```

Or to `replace` fragment do this:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, tab1);
transaction.commit();
```

To pass data from `fragment` you can use `Bundle` as,

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("your_tag", your_string);
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
tab1.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, tab1);
transaction.commit();
```

To know about more `fragment-transaction` check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162369/discussion-on-answer-by-heisen-berg-activitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-ex).